# Android - пример кастомного View, который работает

Tags: android, view

Примеры по [этой](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/index.html) ссылке не работают

Нужен простейший наследник `view`, без дополнительных параметров, у меня не выходит инициализировать его в `layout`'е.

Можете заминусить, главное ответьте

Comment: Покажите ваш код для начала.

Comment: Можно просто код примера? Класс оно не находит. А класс есть

Comment: Если не находит, значит указано не верно. Пока вы не предоставите код именно с вашей проблемой, гадать, что у вас не так никто не будет. Код класса, включая имя пакета и разметка, где вы размещаете свой `View` - для начала.

Comment: сбилдите проект. Как только сбилдите, должно начать работать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/index.html):

```
class PieChart extends View {
    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Использовать:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
   <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Где `com.example.customviews.charting` - имя пакета, в котором ваш класс. Что тут можно сделать не так, не ясно.

Comment: В том то и дело,что оно не находит класс в пакете. Или он должен быть объявлен в отдельном файле?

Comment: @user64675 а как делаете? Один класс, один файл.

Comment: По некоторым причинам для меня было бы предпочтительнее "сваливать" все в 1 файл.

Comment: Error inflating class

Comment: @user64675, таки вам всё верно говорят - один файл - один класс. Если у вас он внутренний, то нужно указать полное имя класса, включая его родителя.

Comment: Но Java, насколько я понял, разрешает пихать несколько классов в 1 файл.

Comment: Вынес в отдельный файл. Ошибка продолжается. Ч.Т.Д.